# Excel VBA Insert Number of Rows for Copied Data using Resize

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy a range of cells from `Workbook1.xlsm` and Insert them in `Workbook2.xltm`.

I will need to insert enough rows in `Workbook2` to 'cope' with the size of the data, which will vary. Thanks to [jspek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5622596/jspek) I've the following macro but this doesn't insert the rows in `Workbook2`.

From much Googling I came to [this](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/insrtrow.htm#insrtrow) . All I can see is that I need to use `.Resize`.

### My Trial Macro

```
sub rangeCopy()
Dim sourceRange As Range, loopRange As Range
Dim targetRange As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim sourceCounter As Long
Dim targetCounter As Long
Dim outString As String
Dim startRow As Long
Dim startCol As Long
Dim endCol As Long
Dim colCounter As Long

Set sourceRange = Sheets("Input Sheet").Range("A9:C800")
Set targetRange = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\j\Documents\Workbook2.xltm").Sheets("Quote").Range("A4")
startRow = sourceRange.Row
lastRow = sourceRange.Rows.Count
startCol = sourceRange.Column
endCol = sourceRange.Columns.Count - 1
Set loopRange = sourceRange.Parent.Cells(startRow, startCol)

For colCounter = 0 To endCol
    targetCounter = 0
    For sourceCounter = 0 To lastRow - 1

        outString = Trim(loopRange.Offset(sourceCounter, colCounter).Value)

        While (Trim(targetRange.Offset(targetCounter, colCounter).Value) <> "")
            targetCounter = targetCounter + 1
        Wend

        targetRange.Offset(targetCounter, colCounter).Value = outString
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Where do you want to paste the data in the Workbook2 ? At the last empty row or at the very first row ?

Comment: I need to paste the data at a prespecified range(ie. from `A4` downwards), but I guess if the macro uses a loop it will be the last empty row. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Okay then first think you need to change is `Set targetRange = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")` to `Set targetRange = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A4")` I will make other changes and post soon :) By the way I don't think you are referring any where to any other workbook in the macro do you want to paste/insert to other worksheet or workbook ?

Comment: Edited original - sorry I didn't realise I copied that code form the origianl so should have edited those `Range`s first.

Comment: Did you tried running that code ?

Comment: Yes, it works fine apart from the fact that it doesn't move down content in `Workbook2` that is below where the copied data needs to go.

Comment: You could just insert copied range at A4 `Rows("4:4").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown` that should save you from everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just the idea of what I was trying to suggest you need to make changes and debug it to suit it to your needs

```
sub rangeCopy()
Dim p As long
Set targetRange = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\j\Documents\Workbook2.xltm").Sheets("Quote").Range("A4")

Dim FRow As Long
Dim m As Long
m =Sheets("Input Sheet").Rows.Count
FRow = Sheets("Input Sheet").Range("A" & m).End(xlUp).Row

Set sourceRange = Sheets("Input Sheet").Range("A9:C" &FRow)
sourceRange.Copy
Sheets("Quote").Rows("4:4").Select Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
p= FRow + 5
Sheets("Quote").Rows("4:" & p).Copy
Sheets("Quote").Rows("4:4").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks - but it comes up with an "Cannot shift object off sheet" error on the `Sheets("Quote").Rows("4:4").Select Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown` line. Would you know why this is?

Comment: Thanks very much works brilliantly! Also, would you know how to just include the values instead of the format?